# how to include or extends a language file in laravel vendor folder

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to load a language folder inside a laravel's package called permissionmanager ,  I know that including files directly inside vendor folder isn't the recommended way, but  trying to extend it on the resources/views/vendor folder was unsuccessful.
  the problem occurs when i try to upload the folder to the server using filezilla,it's not allowed. because i suppose laravel's vendor folder is protected.

[image: language file]
so how can I load that lang file (es/permissionmanager.php) in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "resources/lang" folder, not "resources/views". So it will be:

resources/lang/vendor/backpack/es/permissionmanager.php